# How to publish to artifactory multimodule proj using gradle and spring-boot

Tags: spring, maven, gradle, build, spring-boot

I am using gradle 2.7
I am trying to publish one of my sub-modules into artifactory:

part of my sub modules being upload to snapshort and part of them into release.

```
   apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'



// Since spring-boot does not allow us to configure fat jar name...
task buildForCloud(type: Copy, dependsOn: [clean, build]) {
    from jar.archivePath
    into jar.destinationDir
    rename {
        'com.company.myapp-all.jar'
    }
}


//this module being uploaded into release and as soon as I added this //part I am getting errors
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
            artifact sourceJar {
                classifier "sources"
            }
        }
    }
}


buildForCloud.mustRunAfter(clean)
```

running this way:

```
./gradlew clean buildForCloud publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository
```

the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven2'
   > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project com.mycompany.app:server at /Users/mycomp/IdeaProjects/user-service/server/build/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml
```

Any idea?

Added the gradle log request:

```
Executing task ':server:sourceJar' (up-to-date check took 0.005 secs) due to:
  Output file /Users/comp/IdeaProjects/user-service/server/build/libs/server-1.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar has changed.
  Output file /Users/comp/IdeaProjects/user-service/server/build/libs/server-1.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar has been removed.
:server:sourceJar (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.025 secs.
:server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository
Executing task ':server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Publishing to repository org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository_Decorated@3c888166
[ant:null] An error has occurred while processing the Maven artifact tasks.
 Diagnosis:

Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project com.mycompany.userservice:server at /Users/comp/IdeaProjects/user-service/server/build/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml

:server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository FAILED
:server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.029 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':server:publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven2'
   > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Failed to validate POM for project com.mycompany.userservice:server at /Users/comp/IdeaProjects/user-service/server/build/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 52.274 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
comps-MacBook-Pro-2:user-service comp$ ./gradlew clean buildForCloud -x test publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository -i -
```

Comment: what does the Artifactory logs says? can you post the request and artifactory logs relevant section?

Comment: I only got the gradle logs when it fails. which request do you mean?

Comment: ok I added the gradle request to the question. thank you.

Comment: it's like I have multi modules why 1 module suppose to be uploaded into release-local and other module (server) suppose to be upload into release

Comment: After you run `buildForCloud`, is there a `default-pom.xml` in `user-service/server/build/publications/mavenJava/` ?

Comment: I managed to fix it. now I got other problem when I run publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository (in order to upload my common module into snapshot) then the server module has problems. is it possible to specify on gradle to "ignore" the publication task on specific module for publishMavenJavaPublicationToMaven2Repository? and to make it trigger only for publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository? thx

Comment: Create multiple publications with the appropriate filters. And call the appropriate `publish<publicationName>PublicationTo<Repo>` task

Comment: yes.. how do you filter?:) thank you! would be great if you could provide it by answer and not comment